# Flutter - Create value and name array

Tags: dart, flutter

I´m trying to create value and name array. The problem that i don´t know what is the right way for do this.

```
var send=[];       

    send=[
         'latitud': widget.lat;
    ];
```

Somebody know how can i create array with index and values?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need a `Map` for that

```
var send = {'latitude': widget.lat};
```

If you really need an array, you can use for example an array of maps

```
var send = [{'latitude': widget.lat}, {'latitude': 123.456}];
```

Answer (score 27):

Dart uses Maps for this

to declare  a map and you dont know what you will  your map contain you can use

```
Map<String, dynamic> myObject = {'latitude': widget.lat} ;
```

In your Case you will need a list of objects so you can do it like that :

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> send=[] ;

send.add(myObject) ;
```

Or :

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> send=[] ;

send = [{'latitude': widget.lat}]; \\ if you want to assign it directly
```

Comment: Please could you show me how i could remove the item. I mean would this work send.remove('latitude');